# Java not getting any Tweets using Spark, TwitterUtils, JavaStreamingContext and JavaReceiverInputDStream

Tags: java, apache-spark, twitter, stream

I already managed to get Tweets, but one only.
Generally speaking, there is no error and no Tweet.
It is not a problem with authentication, without using Spark I can get the Tweets.

Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.11.0

Java 1.8

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter.TwitterUtils;

import twitter4j.Status;


public class TweetStream {
    private static void setCredentials(){
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey",
                "");
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret",
                "");
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken",
                "");
        System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret",
                "");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TWS").setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(10000));
        setCredentials();
        Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
        rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR);

        JavaReceiverInputDStream<Status> stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(jssc);
        stream.filter(x -> x.getGeoLocation() != null).foreachRDD(rdd -> rdd.foreach(status -> save(status)));

        jssc.start();
        try {
            jssc.awaitTermination();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void save(Status status) throws IOException {

        System.out.println(status);

    }
}
```

Console:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/06/24 10:26:59 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
17/06/24 10:27:00 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/06/24 10:27:00 WARN Utils: Your hostname, quickstart.cloudera resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface eth1)
17/06/24 10:27:00 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: cloudera
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: cloudera
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(cloudera); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(cloudera); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 39180.
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-b42e754c-3bfb-4997-aed1-22db5d7296f6
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 669.1 MB
17/06/24 10:27:00 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/06/24 10:27:01 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/06/24 10:27:01 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:4040
17/06/24 10:27:01 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/06/24 10:27:01 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 36428.
17/06/24 10:27:01 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.0.2.15:36428
17/06/24 10:27:01 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/06/24 10:27:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 36428, None)
17/06/24 10:27:01 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.0.2.15:36428 with 669.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 36428, None)
17/06/24 10:27:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 36428, None)
17/06/24 10:27:01 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 36428, None)
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding steps to reproduce your issue please?

Comment: I created a new maven project in eclipse and added the dependencies that I will add to the post:

Comment: Can you remove `filter(x -> x.getGeoLocation() != null)` and see if that changes anything?

Comment: I've already removed it. I tested with filter(x -> x.getGeoLocation() == null). I also tried putting filter by hashtag, as explained in that [link](https://github.com/aseigneurin/spark-sandbox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/seigneurin/spark/IndexTweets.java) . e.g. String[] filters = { "#Android" };
        TwitterUtils.createStream(sc, twitterAuth, filters)